# The code doesn't trigger when extending Generic Handler class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a class that inherits from `IHttpHandler`

```
public class MyGenericHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public User user;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        user = Extensions.GetUser();
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm creating a Generic Handler (.ashx) that inherits from the class above:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="test" %>

using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
public class test :MyGenericHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        ((MyGenericHandler)this).ProcessRequest(context);
        context.Response.Write("test");
    }
}
```

But the code `context.Response.Write("test");` never executes. but the one in the first class (`context.Response.Write("test");`) is triggered.

Comment: Shouldn't `ProcessRequest` be virtual in the base class, and override in the inheriting class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: @AndyJ It is as you said. it is overridden in the inheriting class

Comment: Then do you want to edit your question to show that? The code you pasted doesn't have virtual/override on it.

Comment: `MyGenericHandler` is the base class and `ProcessRequest` is overridden in the test class that inherits from `MyGenericHandler`

Comment: Virtual and Override are C# keywords. If you look at my first comment there's a link to the MSDN documentation about it. I added that as an edit after I made the original comment so apologies if you missed it. Here's an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEDkdr Notice the orange warning triangle for one set of classes warning about "hiding". The method will be hidden rather than overridden if you don't use virtual/override, and hiding almost certainly doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: oopss, my bad. It worked now. thanks a lot

Comment: No probs, I've written this up as a proper answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using inheritance in C# you need to use the C# keywords "[virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)" and "[override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)" on the members you wish to override.

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class.
>
> An override method provides a new implementation of a member that is inherited from a base class.

If you don't do this then they will instead be "[hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)" and that almost certainly doesn't work the way you want.

> When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class. When you hide an inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base class version. Although you can hide members without using the new modifier, you get a compiler warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, it suppresses this warning.

Here's an example of some classes, one set using virtual/override, and the other not.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEDkdr

Note the warning triangle letting you know that "hiding" is being used instead of overriding.